# jQuery: 1 ajax request and one function: pass parameters to function

Tags: jquery, parameters, deferred

I have a button click event where I execute multiple steps. Step one is an ajax request and the second step is calling a function passing the button name as a parameter. How do I accomplish this?

```
function buttonClick(e){
    var param1ToBePassed = 1;
    var param2ToBePassed = 2;
    $.when(func1())
    .done(function(){
        $.when(
         $.ajax({}),
         //here I want to call func2 passing in param1tobepassed and param2tobepassed
         funct2(param1ToBePassed, param2ToBePassed ) //this line isn't working
        )
        .done(()=>{console.log('ajax and func2 calls finished');})
    }

}

var func1 = function(){var deferred = new $.Deferred(); /*do somethig;*/ return deferred;}
var func2 = function(param1, param2){var deferred = new $.Deferred(); /*do somethig with param1 and param2;*/ return deferred;}
```

How do I pass param1ToBePassed and param2ToBePassed to func2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function buttonClick(e){
    var param1ToBePassed = 1;
    var param2ToBePassed = 2;
    $.when(func1())
    .done(function(){
        $.when(
         $.ajax(),
         //here I want to call func2 passing in param1tobepassed and param2tobepassed
         funct2(param1ToBePassed, param2ToBePassed ) //this line isn't working
        )
        .done(function(){console.log('ajax and func2 calls finished');})
    });/// I have corrected this added closeing )

}

var func1 = function(){var deferred = new $.Deferred(); /*do somethig;*/ 
return deferred;
}
var func2 = function(param1, param2){var deferred = new $.Deferred(); /*do somethig with param1 and param2;*/
return deferred;
}
```

you have a syntax error I have corrected it in my code above

Comment: I want to run the ajax call and func2 in parallel.

Comment: changed answere

Comment: this snippet has no errors @SoftwareDveloper

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community I don`t need learning techniques to answer

Comment: @IrakliShalamberidze: I believe the response above is because your answer is _mostly_ code without that much explanation. Highlighting what you changed—in this case, the syntax error that you fixed—would likely be more useful for both the OP and future readers with similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are utilizing jQuery, then you can use jQuery's AJAX function. It simplifies a lot of the logic and it's very easy to follow.

Note that the jQuery AJAX function is asynchronous by default. This means you can perform any other tasks, simultaneously, alongside it. For instance, if you don't want to wait for the success request, you can just do a function call anywhere.

```
function buttonClick(e) {
    var param1ToBePassed = 1;
    var param2ToBePassed = 2;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'YOUR_REQUEST_URL',
        method: 'POST', // or GET
        data: {
            // any data to parse?
        },
        success:function(response){                 
            func1(); // this will run on success.
        }
    });
    
    func2(param1ToBePassed, param2ToBePassed); // this will run in parallel with the AJAX function.
}
```

Explanation of the AJAX function:

1. url: here is where you define the path of the request.
2. method: here is where you define the method, e.g. POST or GET request.
3. data: here is where you can parse some data with your request (for instance for data, or whatever you want).
4. success: This is the success function of the AJAX request. It will run once the request is successful.